# How to get 'active' in Bootstrap 4 using Javascript with simple php site

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

Simple three page site, using Bootstrap 4 framework. I am using includes to pull in header.php and footer.php into php pages below. I can't figure out how to add the bootstrap 'active' class to the current nav item for the page the user is currently viewing. I am newbie at javascript but found the javascript below on stack, but it doesn't seem to be working. There are no html errors on the site, and no errors showing on console in web developer tools. All js scripts load ok.

index.php, about.php, faq.php

nav code from header.php

```
        <header>
            <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark navbar-custom">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

code from footer.php

```
        <footer class="footer">
        </footer>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

custom.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     // Get current page URL
     var url = window.location.href;

     // remove # from URL
     url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("#") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("#"));

     // remove parameters from URL
     url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("?") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("?"));

     // select file name
     url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

     // If file name not avilable
     if(url == ''){
     url = 'index.php';
     }

     // Loop all menu items
     $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function(){

      // select href
      var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

      // Check filename
      if(url == href){

       // Add active class
       $(this).addClass('active');
      }
     });
    });
```

css

```
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
        color: rgb(254, 150, 0);
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function(){
  // There is no need to use find('a') since you already pointing to the hrefs
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

It should be:

```
    $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function(){
  // select href
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

With: `$('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link')`, you are already referring to the navlinks which are the hrefs, so there is no need to use `.find('a')`.

Comment: That worked beautifully. After much struggle I see the simple mistake now and learned something new. Thanks so much.